# getComponentAt() return defaultIcon

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, imageicon

I'm trying to get the `defaultIcon` from a `JPanel` containing several images. For examples if I run:

```
System.out.println(mediaPanel.getComponentAt(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY()));
```

It returns:

> `javax.swing.JLabel[,2,0,151x228,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16670644/Projekt/TempPic.png,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=CENTER,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]`

If i press one of the images. The interesting part is the `defaultIcon` that I want to access via a get function but i don't know how.

It clearly has the member `defaultIcon` but how will I access it?

Solved:

```
String getPath = ((JLabel) mediaPanel.getComponentAt(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY())).getIcon().toString();
System.out.println(getPath);
```

This worked!

Comment: [`getIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#getIcon%28%29) ... ?

Comment: getIcon() Worked! (See default question below "Solved:")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String tempString = returnString.substring(indexOf("defaultIcon")+12);
String defaultIcon = tempString.substring(0,indexOf(","));
```

Here `returnString` is the output of `getComponentAt()` metho.

Comment: I get the following error a "returnString" (returnString cannot be resolved) and at "indexOf" (The method indexOf(String) is undefined for the type new MouseListener(){}).

Comment: I told you that returnString is the String returned from getComponentAt method. edited.

Comment: Can't convert Components to String, i tried parse it but without luck.

Comment: Use toString() method